# SSMS- Multiple-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

```
select ci.client_code, ci.cardid,cs.CLIENT_SUIT_ID, cs.EXPIRE_DATE
from client_info ci 
inner join client_info cio on ci.cardid = cio.cardid and cio.client_code like '090%'
inner join client_suit cs on ci.client_code = cs.CLIENT_CODE and cs.EXPIRE_DATE > getdate()
where ci.client_code not like '080%' and ci.client_code not like '090%'

BEGIN TRAN
    update dbo.CLIENT_SUIT_LINE
    set dbo.CLIENT_SUIT_LINE.CLIENT_SUIT_ID = dbo.CLIENT_SUIT.CLIENT_SUIT_ID
    from dbo.CLIENT_SUIT_LINE, dbo.CLIENT_SUIT
    where CLIENT_SUIT.EXPIRE_DATE > getdate() and ci.client_code not like '080%' and ci.client_code not like '090%'
ROLLBACK
```

I'm trying to update my CLIENTSUIT_ID when the expire date of its row is more than today date and it must not start with 080 or 090.The problem i have at the moment is 'the multiple-part identifier "ci.client_code" could not be bound.

Comment: that's because you haven't aliased in bottom query. you have simply pasted form top query and forgotten to edit it.....Also please use ANSI joins. if you don't know what they are please look them up....

Comment: @Mitch Oh i see, thx

Comment: Also why are you using `FROM x, y` syntax? You have no `WHERE` clause that links the two tables - exactly the danger of using this archaic syntax - so I suspect your `UPDATE` is going to affect way more rows than you expect.

Comment: @AaronBertrand My senior told me to put it in there, but i don't know why.I will have a look on that suggestion. Thx, it helps me a lot :D